# How do I test my GtkPrintBackend?

Tags: printing, gtk, gtk3, custom-backend

I am trying to develop my own GtkPrintBackend ,
taking help from here:
https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2006-December/msg00069.html

I want to test my print backend( by making the print dialog use my backend instead). How do I do that?

That is, how do I make the Print dialog use my backend instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here since I figured out a workaround:

I installed jhbuild and built the gtk+ module using jhbuild.
The source code of the corresponding module is downloaded in `~/jhbuild/checkout/<module-name>` .  
Modify the print backends under ~`jhbuild/checkout/gtk+/gtk/modules/printbackends/` directory, and rebuild it (Find instructions to do that [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Jhbuild)).

Now when you launch a gtk application from the jhbuild shell, it will use the modified backend instead of the system default one.